# How to make horizental scroll on ReactJS using MUI Grid

Tags: material-ui, grid, horizontal-scrolling

I want the container direction as "row" above md size screen and "column" below md size screen? How can I implement it?

I am trying to scroll to the horizon using MUI Grid.

```
<Grid
    container
    sx={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: { xs: "column", md: "row" }, overflowX: "auto" }}
  >
    {Array.from(Array(11)).map((_, index) => (
      <Grid item xs={4} sm={6} key={index}>
        <Card key={index} {...featuresData[0]} />
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
```

but it is not working probably.

[image]

Video Link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JkNveJQ1rUUvxuhCY9zI4XGK4tt_9Evd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Would this suit your application? Basically set `xs={12}` on the grid item so that it is always a column until `sm` breakpoint is hit and so on?

For example:

```
 return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      {Array.from(Array(11)).map((_, index) => (
        <Grid xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} key={index} item>
          <MediaCard />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
```

I have put an example up here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-paper-mzxtyd?file=/Demo.tsx) for you to look at.

Comment: Thank you.
But I want to make horizental scroll when only xs breakpoint like as mobile view.

Comment: I uploaded video want to make.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JkNveJQ1rUUvxuhCY9zI4XGK4tt_9Evd/view?usp=sharing